# (swift) remove "\" character from string?

Tags: string, swift, backslash

I have string which contains few `\` and I want to remove all of them. can anyone tell me how can I do that. I have already tried `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` but it's not working out for me.

Comment: Show your tried code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var str = "\\dagdahughuad\\dajughdaug"
var str2 = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
print(str2)
```

This will output

```
dagdahughuaddajughdaug
```

Answer (score 6):

Converted above code in to SWIFT 3

```
    var str = "\\dagdahughuad\\dajughdaug"
    var str2 = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: 
    NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
    print(str2)
```

Answer (score 6):

**swift 5**

for some unicode complex values maybe - with literal

```
let str2 = str1.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

**or** usually

```
let str2 = str1.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```