# Can I make it simpler turning an integer into a string in a specific format using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my audio app, I am playing audio using a progress slider bar -- in the UI, I want to show the amount of time the episode has played. Here's how I am doing that.

```
   @objc func updateSlider(){

        Slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)

        func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
            return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
        }

        let example = (Float(audioPlayer.currentTime))
        let myIntValue = Int(example)
        self.goneTime.text = String(Float(describing: myIntValue)
```

This code updates a label dynamically but it does it in the format of (Int, Int, Int) as specified. Example Output: (1, 5, 20) when I want 1:5:20.

I have tried to modify the format (Int / Int / Int) which is flagged as an error.

A workaround -- but an ugly one -- I found [using this Swift 3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183162/swift-remove-character-from-string): using .replacingOccurrencesOf. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences), it says you can replace one part of the string at a time.

So I change my code to:

```
 func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
            return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
        }

    let example = (Float(audioPlayer.currentTime))
    let myIntValue = Int(example)

    let updated = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: myIntValue)

    let updated2 = String(describing: updated)

    let str2 = updated2.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ":", options:
        NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)

    let str3 = str2.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "", options:
        NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)

    self.goneTime.text = str3
```

This works ok but is there a best practice to simplify these types of modifications? New to Swift and learning.

Comment: Please note that just the **misuse** of `String(describing` – which *translates* the appearance of the tuple literally – causes the two extra replacement steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer `currentTime` instance property returns a `TimeInterval` (Double). You should use `DateComponentsFormatter` and set `unitsStyle` to positional:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let positional: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let seconds: TimeInterval = 3920
let display = Formatter.positional.string(from: seconds)   // "1:05:20"
```

---

Usage in your case:

```
goneTime.text = Formatter.positional.string(from: audioPlayer.currentTime)
```

Comment: Note that `"1:5:20"` it is not the proper format to display TimeInterval

Comment: This is the only (and preferable) solution which handles the zero-padding of the components correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with [Swift Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292):

```
let time = (1, 5, 20)
let myString = "\(time.0):\(time.1):\(time.2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can simply use String InterPolation, to achieve whatever data result you want as follows:

For example :

```
let val1 = 10
let val2 = 20
let val3 = 30

let result = "\(val1) : \(val2) : \(val3)"
print(result) // it will give output: 10:20:30
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can do this in functional way:

```
let time = [1, 5, 20]
let result = time.reduce("", { $0 + ($0.isEmpty ? "" : ":") + "\($1)" })
print(result) // "1:5:20"
```